# How do I grab the column name when looping through a DataTable in VB?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that I'm parsing through and I'm trying to find the column name of a given column when its value = "x".

I'm looping through a `DataTable` like this...

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    For Each cell In row.ItemArray
        columnCount = columnCount + 1
        If cell.ToString() = "x" Then
            Dim columnName As String = [THIS IS WHAT I WANT]
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Is it possible to grab that column name when I'm working through the table in this way?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through the items in `row.ItemArray`, which just contain the values, you need to loop through the items in `dt.Columns`, which contain all the meta data about the columns.  Then you can access the cell value for that column from the row:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        columnCount = columnCount + 1
        Object cell = row(column)
        If cell.ToString() = "x" Then
            Dim columnName As String = column.ColumnName
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
Dim columnname As String = dt.Columns(columncount).ColumnName
```